# Running a feed forward Neural Network in PyTorch Results in an error when run layer by layer vs all at once

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

This is my neural network:

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        # self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=4, kernel_size=3), # 28 x 28 --> 26 x 26 x 4
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=1), # 26 x 26 x 4 
            nn.Flatten(), # --> (26 x 26 x 4)
            nn.Linear(26*26*4, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, X):
        # x = self.flatten(X)
        logits = self.cnn(X)
        return logits
    
    def w_size(self, X):
        print(X.size())
        for layer in self.cnn:
            X = layer(X)
            print(X.size())
        return X
```

When I run the model like this:

```
model.w_size(training_data[0][0])
```

I get this error:

```
torch.Size([1, 28, 28])
torch.Size([4, 26, 26])
torch.Size([4, 26, 26])
torch.Size([4, 26, 26])
torch.Size([4, 676])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [126], line 1
----> 1 model.w_size(training_data[0][0])

Cell In [121], line 23, in NeuralNetwork.w_size(self, X)
     21 print(X.size())
     22 for layer in self.cnn:
---> 23     X = layer(X)
     24     print(X.size())
     25 return X

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py:114, in Linear.forward(self, input)
    113 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x676 and 2704x64)
```

However, when I run the model like this:

```
def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # predictions
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # backprop
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch%100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"Current loss: {loss:>7f}, [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

it works perfectly fine and produces a training output and accuracy in the 80s.

My question is this: why does the model work when I run it the second way (just passing in the input data) but not the first way (passing in one training example to a function)?

[Full Code on GitHub here](https://github.com/ytang07/nn_examples/blob/main/pytorch/cnn_epxloration.ipynb)

[If you want to see the code experiments leading up to this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZKZt-bRaAc)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I was running into this error. It has to do with the fact that the batch size for the train loader was 64 so the correct input size is in fact `64, 1, 28, 28` and not `1, 28, 28`.

Here's the fixed code:

```
input = torch.stack([training_data[x][0] for x in range(0, 64)])
model(input)
```

Just gotta stack 64 of them.

[Here's the git diff](https://github.com/ytang07/nn_examples/commit/c64e55ddfc5a837ad40788adbf3ac034def40d0b?diff=split)

[Here's a video of how I figured this out](https://youtu.be/vIEcbSfAcQg)